# It's possible mix Javascript and C# code in a DOM event in Blazor?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, blazor, webassembly

I'm trying to achieve the next in Blazor WebAssembly; I need to be able to listen for an event in a component, and use both Javscript and C# code like the next way:

```
<button onclick="console.log('Showing event from Js: ' + event); @Test()">Test</button>

@code {
   public void Test()
   {
       JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "Showing log from C#");
   }
}
```

The first problem is that I get the error *"cannot implicitly convert type void to object"*, so if I change the Test method signature just to return an object

```
public object Test()
{
    JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "Showing log from C#");
    return null;
}
```

The App compiles but once the page is loaded, the "Test()" function is executed automatically, and if I click the button, it just executes the Javascript code, and not both pieces of code.

I know I should handle events in Blazor prefixing the event name with "@" symbol in order to call a C# method, and execute Javascript code there using the interop, but in that way, I can't use the default Javascript "event" which I need to use, instead of the Blazor "event" version.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can only have 1 onclick attribute, so either call the C## method from JS or call the JS code from C#. In both cases you will need Interop, there is no support for combining this in the way you are trying to.

> the "Test()" function is executed automatically

Yes, in `onclick="... @Test()"` it is executed when the page renders, not when the button is clicked.

Comment: Yeah, I tried with the interop (From both .NET and Js sides) and it works great, but I wanted to achieve that I mentioned above trying to get a cleaner code, Anyway, thanks for your reply and for clarifying about the reason for the automatic C# method called on render